# Kafka producer publishes messages to one partition out of 4 only

Tags: c, apache-kafka, librdkafka

I have a producer that publishes messages to kafka,
I have 2 brokers with 4 partitions by default, my problem is the producer sends all messages to one partition. (I haven't added more partitions they stay 4 only)
But if I run the same producer code on another VM it runs fine and divides it into partitions, even if I use the console-producer it gets divided.

I have copied snippets from production and made a separate code you can find it on [Github gist](https://gist.github.com/aliabidzaidi/5ab0a313d282d3ebb8cb4a63589e53b8)

```
.
.
.
% Message delivered (263 bytes, partition 0)
% Message delivered (263 bytes, partition 0)
% Message delivered (263 bytes, partition 0)
% Message delivered (263 bytes, partition 0)
% Message delivered (263 bytes, partition 0)
% Message delivered (263 bytes, partition 0)
% Message delivered (263 bytes, partition 0)
% Message delivered (263 bytes, partition 0)
```

**The same code works fine on other instances But only one instance shows this behavior while pushing in kafka, here is a screenshot of stats from kafdrop**

[image: Screenshot from kafdrop]

### Configurations on production,

```
- librdkafka version librdkafka-dev 1.2.1-1 (Also tried it on latest librdkafka release of 1.7)
- Apache Kafka version: kafka_2.13-2.7.0-
- librdkafka client configuration:
    - broker_list=10.120.1.134:9092,10.120.1.135:9092
    - batch_size=2147483647
    - linger_ms=1000
    - message_send_max_retries=1
    - queued_min_messages=10000000
    - queue_buffering_max_kbytes=2147483647
    - queue_buffering_max_messages=2000000
- Operating system: Ubuntu 20.04
- Provide logs (with debug=.. as necessary) from librdkafka
```

Comment: We can't tell if there's a problem with your code if you don't show it to us.  Also, be sure it's in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: I'm as puzzled as you are, its hard to reproduce, it works fine on other VMs, the code is same as [rdkafka_example](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/examples/rdkafka_example.c)

Comment: What do the logs say? https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/examples/rdkafka_example.c#L114-L119 + https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/examples/rdkafka_example.c#L658-L663

Comment: It prints `% Message delivered (285 bytes, partition 0) ` , I'll add my code snippets and its outputs for clarity

Comment: @OneCricketeer you can find the code on [Github gist](https://gist.github.com/aliabidzaidi/5ab0a313d282d3ebb8cb4a63589e53b8).

Comment: Thanks. I don't really know the librdkafka code, and I'd be shocked to learn it's machine specific (maybe you should recompile librdkafka?). In any case, might be worth a Github issue if no one here would be able to reproduce your problem